# How to add an item to a listbox with PyWinAuto?

Tags: python, automation, ui-automation, pywinauto

I am using Python Version 3.8.2 (64bit)
I am using PyWinAuto version 0.6.8

I am trying to automate a windows desktop app. I need to add items to a listbox.

so Far I can print the number of items in the list box. No problem

```
    app = Application()
app.connect(path=r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Example\WindowsFormsApp.exe")

#Get a dialog...
dlg = app.top_window()
dlg.print_control_identifiers()

#Click the 'Generate File' buton'
windowHandle = app.window(best_match='Example Windows Forms App')
listBox = windowHandle.ListBox
print("**********************************") 
print(listBox.item_count())
print("**********************************")
```

does anyone out there know how I would add an item to the listBox?

Comment: Not sure it's technically possible. It's editing task, not an automation one. Which backend do you use for creating `app` object?

Comment: To be honest with you , I am not sure. |I don't specifically set a back end, soguessing PyWinAuto mst usea default backend? I shall update the code listing in my orig. Post so you can see the code I used

Comment: By the way The control I am trying to access is of type WindowsForms10.LISTBOX. we manually drag / drop a file over the listbox and the path of the file is displayed in said listbox. I would like to programatically add the string representing the file path to the listbox.. Like you say, maybe this can't be done - but I'd at least like to try.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default backend is "win32". But fortunately it's correct backend to try adding an element to the list box. You can try `.send_message(LB_ADDSTRING, wParam, 0)`. `wParam` for this message can be found in the Microsoft docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/lb-addstring

You will need `ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(...)` or `ctypes.create_string_buffer(...)` for wParam depending on the application is Unicode or not.

Example of similar call to `send_message` can be found in `def set_edit_text` implementation in `win32_controls.py` in pywinauto source code. It's not so complicated.

Hope it helps.

Comment: It's possible to face with another technical issue: the memory for the string should be in remote (app) process. Then you will need `RemoteMemoryBlock` to allocate the string memory in the target process. Without it you may face the app crash or `send_message` failure. Crash may happen after script exit because Python process with the allocated memory has died.

Comment: I've added feature request to the GitHub repo: https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues/933 But we may find time for it after 1-2 years of waiting due to other priorities.